# Compare Images In 2D Array Of PictureBoxes

Tags: arrays, vb.net, comparison, 2d, picturebox

I have a bit of code here (2D array of pictureboxes) that checks if an image belonging one row down from the selected index is equal to My.Resources.NONE. It then performs an image swap between the two indexes if true. The problem here is that it never detects it properly.

```
If mypic(x + 1, y).Image Is My.Resources.NONE Then
        mypic(x + 1, y).Image = mypic(x, y).Image
        mypic(x, y).Image = My.Resources.NONE
End If
```

If I remove the If statement, it works fine on all images I click on. My problem is I ONLY want it to perform a swap if the image below the one being selected has an image value of My.Resources.NONE. Any idea why this would not be working? The If statement never seems to be true even though it seems as if it should be.

UPDATE:

I stopped using My.Resources.NONE and simply started using "Nothing"

```
If mypic(x + 1, y).Image Is Nothing Then
        mypic(x + 1, y).Image = mypic(x, y).Image
        mypic(x, y).Image = Nothing
End If
```

It now works except for the first line in the if statement. It is not setting mypic(x + 1, y).Image to mypic(x, y).image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! I was not adding the blank one to the panel in the beginning. Silly me!

```
Me.Controls.Add(mypic(r, c))
mypic(r, c).BringToFront()
```